# Limit checkbox in JSON

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

Can anyone help me please, i've been trying to make some quizzes, and i put my questions in JSON file. then, i want to make answer for this quizzes in checkbox and the user must answer two checkbox options. my question is how to limit the checkbox so the user only answer two checkboxes and they can't choose more than two or just only one checkboxes? can i using if else in JSON? or should i put the questions in views instead JSON? or should i add content_url to link to the views file and putting some settings like limitation etc in views files? or anyone have any suggestion for my case? i'm using php with CI 3 btw and i'm still learning and sorry for my bad english because i'm not english speaker.

This is my code in json:

```
    "part": "question",
            "type": "choice_checkbox",
            "choices": [
                {
                        "choice_text": "A. Pasif",
                        "choice_variable": "A",
                        "choice_value": 1
                },
                {
                        "choice_text": "B. Delusi ",
                        "choice_variable": "B",
                        "choice_value": 1
                },
                {
                        "choice_text": "C. Konsumtif",
                        "choice_variable": "C",
                        "choice_value": 1
                },
                {
                        "choice_text": "D. Patuh",
                        "choice_variable": "D",
                        "choice_value": 1
                },
                {
                        "choice_text": "E. Aktif",
                        "choice_variable": "E",
                        "choice_value": 1
                },
                {
                        "choice_text": "F. Teratur",
                        "choice_variable": "F",
                        "choice_value": 1
                }
            ]
```

Comment: The issue isn’t with the json, can you please share your PHP code that’s validating the check boxes?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a question with multiple answers (choices), I would recommend you to make two different validations:

The first one in the client side, using Javascript.

The second one in CodeIgniter, creating a custom validation method. Without the code of your application it's not easy to make an example, but this could help:

**HTML (part of the form you should submit)**

```
<p>Question 1:</p>
<input type="checkbox" name="questions[0][]" id="choice_1_1" value="Choice 1 Value">
<label for="choice_1_1">Choice 1 to Question 1</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="questions[0][]" id="choice_1_2" value="Choice 2 Value">
<label for="choice_1_2">Choice 2 to Question 1</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="questions[0][]" id="choice_1_3" value="Choice 3 Value">
<label for="choice_1_3">Choice 3 to Question 1</label>

<p>Question 2:</p>
<input type="checkbox" name="questions[1][]" id="choice_2_1" value="Choice 1 Value">
<label for="choice_2_1">Choice 1 to Question 2</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="questions[1][]" id="choice_2_2" value="Choice 2 Value">
<label for="choice_2_2">Choice 2 to Question 2</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="questions[1][]" id="choice_2_3" value="Choice 3 Value">
<label for="choice_2_3">Choice 3 to Question 2</label>

<!-- etc... -->
```

**CodeIgniter**

```
<?php

class Example extends CI_Controller {

        public function index()
        {
                // Loading the CI form helper (optional)
                $this->load->helper('form');
                
                // The CI form validation library
                $this->load->library('form_validation');

                // Set other form validations here...

                // Set custom validations here...
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('questions[]', 'Questions', 'callback_questions_check');

                // Run the validations...
                if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
                {
                        // If the validations failed (or the form wasn't submitted)...
                }
                else
                {
                        // If everything is OK...
                }
        }


        public function questions_check($questions)
        {
                // Read questions[] field (works as an array)...
                foreach ($questions as $question)
                {
                        // Check if every question has two checkboxes checked (works as an array too)...
                        if (count($question) != 2)
                        {
                                // If not, set an error message and return FALSE...
                                $this->form_validation->set_message('questions_check', 'The {field} must have two values checked');
                                return FALSE;
                        }
                }

                // If there are no errors, return TRUE...
                return TRUE;
        }
}
```

As I said, it's not easy to check this code fits on yours, but if you have any doubt you can find more information right here: http://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html?highlight=validation#callbacks-your-own-validation-methods